# Make the first nav item start off closed in accordion menu

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I did this tutorial:

http://michaeljacobdavis.com/tutorials/statesavingaccordion.html
here is the demo page:
http://michaeljacobdavis.com/tutorials/statesavingaccordion/statesavingaccordion.html#1

I hooked it up just fine, but I do not want the First Menu Item open (About) when the user visits the site for the first time.  I want all the Main Menu items to be closed so the user can't see the sub-nav items until they click on one.  I tried but couldn't figure out how to do this - please help.  Below is the code - the About section is always opened when the site first opens - i'd like it closed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery().ready(function(){
$('#navbar').accordion({
    autoHeight: false,
    navigation: true,
    header: '.navbaritem'
});

$(".navbaritem").click(function(event){
      window.location.hash=this.hash;
 });    
});
</script>

    <div id="navbar">
<div id="logo"> <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" width="234" height="191" border="0" /></a></div>    
<div class="navitemback">
<a class="navbaritem" href="#about" title="First Menu Item" name="about">about</a>
<div>
    <p><a href="#why">why we do it</a></p>
    <p><a href="#press">press/awards</a></p>
    <p><a href="#bio">bio</a></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="navitemback">
<a class="navbaritem" href="#commercial" title="Second Menu Item" name="commercial">commercial</a>
<div>
    <p><a href="#olivers">olivers</a></p>
    <p><a href="#lemonade">lemonade</a></p>
    <p><a href="#court">court</a></p>
    <p><a href="#macks">macks</a></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="navitemback">
<a class="navbaritem" href="#residential" title="Third Menu Item" name="residential">residential</a>
    <div>
    <p><a href="#city">city</a></p>
    <p><a href="#states">states</a></p>
    <p><a href="#country">country</a></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$('#navbar').accordion({
    autoHeight: false,
    navigation: true,
    header: '.navbaritem',
    active: false,
    collapsible: true 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hiya **Demo** :) http://jsfiddle.net/aCeyn/

Also you can do this without `collapsible` like this:

Hope this helps! have a nice one, cheers!

further if you want to read other properties or code see here: http://michaeljacobdavis.com/tutorials/statesavingaccordion/jquery-ui.min.js

Oh and also you can feel free to play around with the jsfiddle and put styling on for your use!

**Jquery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#testMenu').accordion({
        autoHeight: false,
        navigation: true,
        header: '.testMenuItem',
        active: false
    });

    $(".testMenuItem").click(function(event){
          window.location.hash=this.hash;

     });    


});​
```

Comment: @user1269988 no worries man all good, Please do not forget to accept the answer, mentioning you as you seem to be new, Thanks!